# YouTube search for any query cost 100 queries?

Tags: android, kotlin, networking, youtube-api, kotlin-coroutines

Looking by this page -

https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/determine_quota_cost

Under the "search" function I see that it costs 100 queries per use. I don't know if "search" means the `q` query parameter in the endpoint, and this is why I am trying to figure out. When I am using the following network call in my app -

```kotlin
interface YoutubeApi {

    const val BASE_URL = "https://youtube.googleapis.com/"

    @GET("youtube/v3/search?part=snippet&maxResults=3")
    suspend fun searchYoutubeVideos(
        @Query("q") searchQuery : String,
        @Query("key") apiKey : String
    ) : NetworkResponse<YoutubeSearchResultModel,String>
}
```

My call always results in costing 100 queries, regardless of me asking only for 3 objects, which is pretty expensive. Am I doing something wrong or this is how it works and this is the price for each search in the YouTube API?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[YouTube Data API v3](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3) [Search: list](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list) endpoint is very expensive, consider applying for [quota extension](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/getting-started#quota).

Answer (score 1):

Sadly, `maxResults` is not connected with quota cost. It's always 100 points, as clearly stated in [their docs](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list), regardless of the number of results per page.
Also, every subsequent call while requesting the next page has a cost of 100 points itself (one single search, 3 pages of results, 300 points)